# How to enable IRQ8 in my OS kernel?

Tags: c++, operating-system, kernel

I want to know that, how to enable IRQ8 (RTC) in my own Kernel written in C++.
I already have the module for installing interrupt handlers.
But after installing IRQ8 interrupt handlers it doesn't generate any interrupt.
So how can i enable IRQ8 ? and after enabling it what interrupt it will generate ?
I know that RTC generates INT 70h interrupt, but i am installing RTC interrupt handler on 
int 29h in IDT. So that it's not working.

Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: What exactly is the operating system you are referring to as the 'C/C++ kernel'? Did you write it yourself from scratch?

Comment: What OS are you talking about?

Comment: There is no "C/C++" kernel. A kernel is part of an operating system, not a language. The real problem is that you haven't specified the operating system (or even the architecture), therefore the question cannot be answered.

Comment: I am writting my own kernel in C++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you're working with an x86-based architecture, and if that's so, then you're also working with a 8259A programmable interrupt controller.  If that's the case, IRQ8 is located on the second slave PIC, which is typically wired through IRQ2 on the master PIC.  You are basically going to have to program IRQ2 on the master PIC to receive the cascaded INT signals from the slave PIC.  Next, you are going to have to unmask any masked interrupts on the second slave PIC, which in this case would be IRQ8 where the RTC interrupts are typically wired.

The ports for controlling these two PICs can be found at `0x020` and `0x21` for the master PIC, and `0xA0` and `0xA1` for the slave PIC.  There are four different `ICW`s, or initialization command words that can be used to program these two PIC's.  In order to setup cascading, you will need to send a ICW1 to the master PIC at port `0x20`, and set the second bit to `1` in order to tell the PIC that it is in cascade mode.  You will then need to write the ICW3 value `0x02` to port `0x21` to tell the master pic that it will be receiving the slave INT signals on the second pin from the slave PIC.  Finally you will need to program the proper ICW's to the second slave PIC at `0xA0` and `0xA1` in order to unmask and enable the RTC on IRQ8 (i.e., the slave PIC's first interrupt pin).  You can also at that time program the slave PIC to request the appropriate interrupt value offset into the IDT where you interrupt handler is located.

There's quite a bit of documentation out there on how to correctly send ICW's (initialization command words) as well as OCW's (operational command words) to each of the PIC's at their respective ports.  A lot of these commands are sequential, meaning you will need to follow a couple steps in a specific ordering, since there are 4 ICW's, and 3 OCW's, but you are writing them to only two 8-bit ports for each PIC.  For a quick reference on the bit masks for each type, you can refer to http://stanislavs.org/helppc/8259.html, but I would suggest also looking for some additional documentation if you are unfamiliar with programming ports, etc. For example, programming ports requires some assembly ... if you want, you can make some wrappers, but you will need the x86 `IN` and `OUT` assembly commands, as well as control of specific registers such as `AX`, `AL`, and `DX` to read and write to a port.

Finally, if none of the above works, you *may* need to actually parse the Intel MP table in order to figure out how your platform is wired up ...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My problem is still unsolved.I am installing irq8 interrupt handler on IDT at 29h entry, and i am able to enable irq8, but irq8 generates interrupt 70h, so that its not working for me.

Comment: I have a querry can you please explain me.I have installed irq1 interrupt handler on IDT at 21h entry.But according to this document <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS_interrupt_call> on key press keyboard should generate 09h interrupt, But it is generating 21h interrupt, so keyboard is working fine.But technically it should generate 09h interrupt, why is this not happening?

Comment: Once you re-program the PIC to send another interrupt vector for an IRQ, you can pretty much go to any valid IDT entry you want for the keyboard or anything else.  This is done all the time when going into 32-bit protected mode since the first couple interrupts that the BIOS normally uses are reserved for processor exceptions.  So while the PIC might start off sending one vector value, you can always program it to send something else.  This can be done by sending the proper ICW and OCW commands to the PIC on its respective I/O port, which is why I suggest you reference some documentation

Comment: Keep in mind that once you exit 16-bit real-mode and go into 32-bit protected mode, you no longer have access to the BIOS interrupt vectors, and you are going to be forced to use the IDT ...  Therefore the wikipedia document you referenced is irrelevant once you're in 32-bit protected mode.  The PIC though, if you don't re-program it, will try to keep using the old interrupt vector values, which will create a lot of problems.  So not only do you need to install interrupt handlers in the IDT, but you need to re-program the PIC.

Comment: Thank you so much it solves my problem. You are simply great, But now i am facing another problem.Now i am able to generate IRQ8 interrupt, But it is generating only once.How about periodic. I am using this:`outb(0x70, 0x0b);   
 int regB = inb(0x71);
 outb(0x70, 0x0b);
 outb(0x71, regB | 0x40)`     for enabling IRQ8

Comment: Did you forget to clear the interrupt mask on the slave PIC (i.e., send and `EOI` to the PIC) before exiting your interrupt handler?

Comment: Yes, i did it but still not working.I send EOI to both PIC before exiting handler.

Comment: I made some changes. I use register C, but still not working.Interrupt is generating but only once.

Comment: Solved Now. Thank you so much `Jason`.Can you please tell me which books should i refer to know more about this.

Comment: What was the problem that you were able to solve? ... As for books, the first place I would suggest going is the Intel processor documentation, especially volume 3A, as well as various other documents from Intel on PIC's, the MP tables, bootloader requirements, etc.  Osdev.org is also a great resource.  Finally Carnegie Mellon has a [great course on OS-implementation](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~410/), and they have the class notes online.  Look up a past year since the current course is not complete ...

Comment: There was a small small mistake in my code.IRQ8 was installing at 41 instead of 40, That i solved. Then IRQ8 interrupt generating only once, so for that i use register C before the end of handler.That is `outb(0x70, 0x0C);
 inb(0x71);`.I got it from osdev.org itself. Thank you for references, defiantly i will go through that. Thanks

Comment: LOL - you will go through that... [defiantly](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/defiantly)? Great answer, Jason!